# Tools to diagnose Spring application and find out why it starts so slow

Tags: spring, spring-boot, performance

Recently I found out that it took about 10 minutes to start my Spring Application. I googled, but only find some benchmark tools like [spring-boot-startup-bench](https://github.com/dsyer/spring-boot-startup-bench), So is there any tools that can help me found out which module in my application needs to be optimized.

Comment: Have you tried to increase the logging level to TRACE and see where it takes time?

Comment: @GuillaumeF. No, I will try it.Thanks

Comment: start _where_? locally, kubernets pod, etc?

Comment: @Eugene k8s pod

Comment: @ChaojunZhong you might want tocheck your cpushares